# Chosen jquery script with cakephp - Trying to save an array from data

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to save on my "Requestc" controller an array with data from a Multiselect chosen script.

My view:

```
<select data-placeholder="Selecione as certidões" name="certidoes[Requestc][][caminho]" multiple="multiple"  style="width:400px;" class="chzn-select">
    <?php foreach ($certidao as $certidoes): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $certidoes['Certificate']['id']; ?>"><?php echo $certidoes['Certificate']['nome']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

My controller:

```
if(!empty($solicitacao)) {
        $this->request->data['Requestc']['request_id'] = $this->Request->id;
        $data = $this->request->data['certidoes'];
        $this->Request->Requestc->saveAll($data['Requestc']);
    }
```

And when I save my "request_id", it's still blank.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the FormHelper to generate your inputs? [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)

Comment: Im using chosen script...

Comment: As far as I can see, this output could be created with the FormHelper without problems, outputting the data-placeholder attribute should not be a problem if you pass it in the 'options' array. Anyway, have you tried to `debug($this->request)` to see what your form is sending and what is received in your controller?

Comment: The line `$this->request->data['Requestc']['request_id'] = $this->Request->id;` its ok. Returning the Request-> id fine. Apparently the problem is save the `$this->Request->id` at the same time of the `$data`. I'll try to make the output with FormHelper but i'm not realizing how it will help me!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not a answer, but to illustrate how this input can be created with the FormHelper;

```
// Aparently, this variable is not formatted correctly to be used
// directly for options. If possible, use Model::find('list')
// to get it in the right format
$options = array();

foreach ($certidao as $row) {
    $options[$row['Certificate']['id']] = $row['Certificate']['nome'];
}


echo $this->Form->input('Requestc.caminho', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'data-placeholder' => 'Something here',
    'style' => 'width:400px',
    'class' => 'chzn-select',
    'options' => $options,
 );
```

Not behind my computer to test, but think it should be fine

Comment: I do as you said. Change for FormHelper. This work fine. But when I save show this error:

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `societario`.`requests_certidoes` (`request_id`, `caminho`) VALUES (55, Array)

Comment: My data:

`array(
 'Request' => array(
  'motivo' => 'Licitação',
  'nome_licitacao' => '',
  'data_pregao' => '',
  'nome_cliente' => '',
  'outros' => ''
 ),
 'Requestc' => array(
  'caminho' => array(
   (int) 0 => '1',
   (int) 1 => '3'
  ),
  'request_id' => '60'
 )
)`

Comment: It seems the naming of the fields is not right for the type of relationships. It's a bit hard for me to fully understand your Model-relations, because of the non-English names, is it `Request -> HABTM -> Certificate` or `Request -> hasMany -> ?something?`. Also read this part of the documentation, it may give some clues on how to name your fields/inputs: [Saving Related Model Data (hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)

Comment: `Request -> hasMany -> Requestc` the foreignKey is "request_id" that is "60". "caminho" are the options of the checkboxes. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use a different syntax to modify the data. [Check the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest%3a%3adata)

```
// Modify some request data, so you can prepopulate some form fields.
$this->request->data('Post.title', 'New post')
    ->data('Comment.1.author', 'Mark');
```